# Elasticsearch: Difference between an IndexRequest and an UpdateRequest

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Could someone explain the difference between an [IndexRequest](http://javadoc.kyubu.de/elasticsearch/HEAD/index.html?org/elasticsearch/action/index/IndexResponse.html) and an [UpdateRequest](http://javadoc.kyubu.de/elasticsearch/HEAD/org/elasticsearch/action/update/UpdateRequest.html) for Elasticsearch? The javadoc for the UpdateRequest (class level) is blank and I can't find any documentaion for it.

I found some code that wraps an `IndexRequest` inside an `UpdateRequest` before adding it to a bulk operation, but I found that the `BulkRequestBuilder` does not need the `UpdateRequest` and can take an `IndexRequest` directly, is there any advantage to doing this one way or the other?

```
IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(indexName, typeName, docId)
    .source(doc);
UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest(indexName, typeName, docId)
    .doc(doc)
    .upsert(indexRequest);
```

I have also observed that you can set the document timestamp on an `IndexRequest`, but not on an `UpdateRequest`. If the `IndexRequest` is wrapped in an `UpdateRequest`, and the doc is a new doc, then the timestamp will be written into Elasticsearch, but if the doc already exists, then the timestamp will be ignored and will be set to the current time. Is there any documentation anywhere that describes this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

`IndexRequest` defines the **document** to add to ElasticSearch, as opposed to `UpdateRequest` which actually **performs** the addition into ElasticSearch.

Note: `UpdateRequest.upsert()` expects a separate `IndexRequest` to be used just if the document does not exist. This enables you to use a partial doc for cases where the doc already exists.